# How to make whole words move to next line in a responsive div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Some text is overflowing the div and won't wrap onto the next line. I don't want to use `word-break` because I want the whole words to be displayed. In this example *"medieval, renaissance and"* are not wrapping, this line is overflowing the div at md width. I'm using Bootstrap columns.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            And so it was indeed: she was now only ten inches high, and her face early modern art brightened up at the medieval, renaissance and and she was now the right size for going through the little door into that lovely garden.
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            You will openly cultural haberdashery from across the world to reassess a calls of judgement values granted to medieval, renaissance and early fashion art that have often been taken as renegades.
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 ">
            After a time she heard a little pattering of feet in the distance, and she hastily dried her eyes to see what was coming. It was the White Rabbit returning, splendidly dressed.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that there might be a hidden character or something hidden making this issue, I just remove the space before and after the word ***renaissance*** and it worked fine.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            And so it was indeed: she was now only ten inches high, and her face early modern art brightened up at the medieval, renaissance and and she was now the right size for going through the little door into that lovely garden.
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            You will openly cultural haberdashery from across the world to reassess a calls of judgement values granted to medieval, renaissance and early fashion art that have often been taken as renegades.
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 ">
            After a time she heard a little pattering of feet in the distance, and she hastily dried her eyes to see what was coming. It was the White Rabbit returning, splendidly dressed.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: After much testing this appears to be the answer. I know it's not the exciting technical answer we're looking for on stackoverflow, but this did fix the issue on the live site. I had to remove the space after the comma and type it in again.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with Bootstrap 4 Utilities classes: [Text | Utilities / Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/)

You can add the class: `.text-break` to your div.

Comment: Thanks, unforunately that cuts the words up. I now have the word renaissance displaying as renaissanc on one line and the e on the next line. I want the whole word to move to the next line.

Comment: Maybe, in your case, you need to use: .text-wrap